# Get parent menu item of a current node

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to get the parent menu item of node I am currently on:

```
$node_id = // some id
$menu_link_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link');
$menu_link = $menu_link_manager->loadLinksByRoute('entity.node.canonical', array('node' => $node_id));
$parent = $menu_link->getParent();
```

but for some reason it always fails with this error:

```
Error: Call to a member function getParent() on array
```

When I inspect `$menu_link` I can clearly see it is there:

[image]

Also the method of `getParent()` seems to be correct: [Docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21MenuLinkInterface.php/interface/MenuLinkInterface/9.0.x)

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[loadLinksByRoute](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21MenuLinkManager.php/function/MenuLinkManager%3A%3AloadLinksByRoute/9.2.x) returns an array of `\Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkInterface`. So when you called:

```
$menu_link_manager->loadLinksByRoute()
```

You got back an array not an object (Drupal frequently returns arrays in places you might be expecting an object). Your route can be on more than one menu link, so you may want to think about what you pull from that array, but the easiest solution is pull the first element in the array using [reset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) or [array_pop()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php).

Comment: $menu_links = $menu_link_manager->loadLinksByRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $nid]);